# Django + React Project could not load static files

Tags: javascript, html, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am having a Django and React application together in one project folder.

Project Structure:

```
project/
  frontend/ 
    src/
      components/
        App.jsx
      index.js
    static/
       frondend/
         main.js
    templates/
       frondend/
         index.html
    migrations/
     __init__.py
     admin.py
     apps.py
     models.py
     test.py
     urls.py
     views.py
  project/  
    migrations/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    test.py
    urls.py
    views.py

  nodemodules/
 .bablerc
  manage.py
 .webpack.config.js
 package-lock.json
 package.json
```

**index.html:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css">
    <title>Django DRF - React : Quickstart - </title>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <div>
            <div id="root">
                <!-- React -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'frontend/main.js' %}"></script>

</html>
```

My .bablerc file:
    {

```
"presets": [
"es2015", "stage-1", "react"
```

],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-runtime",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "react-hot-loader/babel",
        "typecheck",
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
        "add-module-exports",
        "import-asserts"
    ]
}

my webpack.config.js:

```js
    const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./frontend/templates/frontend/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

The problem here is that my static files won't get loaded with

```html
{% load static %}
```

statement.

**dev**:
    from project.settings.common import *

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['stockdata.routers.StockdataRouter',]
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '*****',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'connect_timeout': 0,
    }
},
'data_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'sdata',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '*****',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
   },
 }

 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "frontend/static/"),
 ]
```

**production-settings:**

```
from project.settings.common import *
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['aws.ip',]

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['stockdata.routers.StockdataRouter',]
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'dbname',
    'USER': 'awsuser',
    'PASSWORD': '******',
    'HOST': '*****.******.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    'PORT': '5432',
    # 'HAS_HSTORE': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'connect_timeout': 0,
    },
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0
},
'data_db': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'data_db',
    'USER': 'awsuser',
    'PASSWORD': '*******',
    'HOST': '*****.******.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    'PORT': '5432',
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0
}
}
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

Is there an yway I can get my static files loaded here in React HTML.

And also, if this way of configuration seems to be the wrong approach then please help me on step-by-step proper implementation on Django + React project.

Thanks in advance.

> After searching, I figured out that problem is with something related to "Base_Url", Because if hit "127.0.0.1:8000/static/frontend/main.js" , this will successfully open my js file. So can someone please help me to fix this.

Comment: try `{% load staticfiles %}`

Comment: did you set `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `STATIC_URL` in setting .py, if yes then post it

Comment: @Pankaj Sharma:  dev-settings:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "frontend/static/"),
]

Comment: tried with staticfiles, but that doesn't work

Comment: Can you share your settings.py?

Comment: in `urls.py`  add `+ static(MEDIA_URL, document_root=os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT,'accounts'))` after urlpatterns

Comment: @rwx check my question, I have edited with settings code.

Comment: @PankajSharma I do have this in my urls.py file.

Comment: How about replacing `STATIC_URL` with `frontend`? And I would like to use something like nginx or python's http.server, not django, to serve static files, in such mixing scenario.

Comment: @BenLee Thank you. Can you please provide some resource to configure application with ngnix or python's http server, It would be a great help.

Comment: `python3 -m http.server -d frontend 80` can serve the files under folder `frontend`, where your .js and .html files should be. In python2, it's SimpleHTTPServer. However, this method is just like a toy. Just search `nginx` for the tutorial, and [this](https://nginx.org/en/docs/) is documentations